# how to change in panorama horizontal width in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, wrappanel, panorama-control

I would like to create a page in panorama in WP7, using wrap panel in the content.

I would like to create something like the People Hub, a few hubtile (i.e. 5) and spend across the width larger than in 1 single panorama Item width.

I'd try to set the wrap panel width, panoramaItem width, still no chance getting it work like in PeopleHub.

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with 8 TileButton ([Bewise controls](http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/)) but it's the same with Hubtile

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="home" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="850">
                <Grid>
                    <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,86" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Height="380">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Bewise:TileButton ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                    <TextBlock Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,389,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="view all" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Width="201" />
                </Grid>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Answer (score 3):

For changing the width of a panorama item just set the Orientation = "Horizontal". I think this will solve your problem.

Regards

Comment: this doesn't work! If just set the "orientation to "Horizontal", it will bring the next HunTile to next line, it doesn't growth to the next side.